# What does this c++ function mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
template <typename R, typename T>
Deferred<Future<R>()> defer(const PID<T>& pid, Future<R> (T::*method)())
{ 
  return Deferred<Future<R>()>([=]() { return dispatch(pid, method); });
}
```

1. what does `(T::*method)` mean? I know what's `T` here. But never seen something like `*method` . The preceding `*` has got me confused.
2. The function body seems pretty complicated. I would love to understand it syntactically by breaking down each part. Looks to me like lambda though.

Comment: A member function pointer and a lambda function that defers it to a `dispatch()` call.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. what does (T::*method) mean? I know what's T here. But never seen something like *method . The preceding * has got me confused.

```
 Future<R> (T::*method)()
```

is a member function pointer parameter named `method`. It's expected to get the address of a member function of `T` with the signature `Future<R> func();`.

> 2. The function body seems pretty complicated. I would love to understand it syntactically by breaking down each part. Looks to me like lambda though.

It is a lambda function call, yes. The lambda body calls `dispatch()` and passes on the `pid` and `method` parameters.

Comment: OK. But what does [=]() mean?

Comment: It's the _by copy capture default_ as explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Please spent more efforts about reading the available documentation (that's a very nice way to tell you RTFM). I didn't DV your question BTW.